# Difference Between @magentoAdminConfigFixture and @magentoConfigFixture

Tags: magento2, integration-test

When writing integration tests, there are two quite similar annotations:

1. `@magentoAdminConfigFixture` ([GitHub](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/dev/tests/integration/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Annotation/AdminConfigFixture.php))
2. `@magentoConfigFixture` ([GitHub](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/dev/tests/integration/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Annotation/ConfigFixture.php))

The latter one is used much more often:

```
$ grep -R '@magentoAdminConfigFixture ' vendor/magento/ | wc -l
110
$ grep -R '@magentoConfigFixture ' vendor/magento/ | wc -l
1828
```

However, I cannot find any documentation about the difference (see [related DevDocs issue](https://github.com/magento/devdocs/issues/7936)). Some config values are even used in both ways in the core:

```
$ grep -R '@magentoAdminConfigFixture admin/security/use_form_key' vendor/magento/ | wc -l
8
$ grep -R '@magentoConfigFixture admin/security/use_form_key' vendor/magento/ | wc -l
5
```

What is the difference between the two? When should I use which one?

Answer (score 0):

**@magentoConfigFixture**

You can use this annotation when you need to set some config value before the test starts. The format for this annotation is:

```
/**
 * @magentoConfigFixture store_code section/group/field value
 */
```

It will set the `value` for the configuration field with the path `section/group/field` for the store that has the code `store_code`.

**@magentoAdminConfigFixture**

Similar to `magentoConfigFixture` except that it sets values for default scope so you cannot pick stores.

Reference: https://dusanlukic.com/annotations-in-magento-2-integration-tests

Comment: To be honest, "similar" does not convince me :D I would like to know the exact difference.